# Hacklang: Cannot return Vector from (function(...): KeyedIterable<arraykey, mixed>)

Tags: generics, return-type, hacklang

I have a method that might return either a Map or a Vector, and since both types implement `KeyedIterable` — `Vector<T>` specifically implementing `KeyedIterable<int, T>` — I figured I could cover both cases with a `KeyedIterable<arraykey, T>` return type. However, even though `arraykey` is a more general type than `int`, this doesn't work. For example, the typechecker complains on the following code:

```
<?hh // strict
class A {
   public static function foo(): KeyedIterable<arraykey, mixed> {
      return Vector{};
      /*
      Invalid return type (Typing[4110])
      This is an array key (int/string)
      It is incompatible with an int
      Considering that this type argument is invariant with respect to KeyedIterable
      */
   }
}
```

Why can't I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `KeyedIterable` isn't read-only, so can't take a subtype.

For instance, `A::foo()->toMap()` will have the type `Map<arraykey, mixed>` from the type signatures, but the actual type `Map<int, mixed>`.

Comment: By [the example provided in the docs](http://hhvm.com/blog/9215/covariance-contravariance-and-super-type-constraints) I've just found now, I can understand why generally only read-only entities can be covariant, but I don't understand why `A::foo()->toMap()` actually being `Map<int, mixed>` is a problem. I can't imagine anything illegal I can do with it, since anything I can do with the `int` keys I should be able to do with the `arraykey` keys, right?

Comment: @concat You can add a string key value to the `Map<arraykey, mixed>`, which is invalid for `Map<int, mixed>` (`$map['foo'] = 'baz';` is valid for `arraykey`, but not `int`)